# Loading external javascript not working, trying to animate HTML elements with Textillate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Some of you may be familiar with Textillate. ( https://jschr.github.io/textillate/ ) On the website, it says to fully implement the animations, I have to make sure I include JQuery, animate.css ( http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ ) and lettering.js (https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js). Ofcourse, I also have to implement the textillate.js file.

For some reason, I'm not able to get this working, I think I'm making a mistake with loading in the javascript or JQuery files. Sadly, the console doesn't display any errors, so it's a bit strange..

My code to make it work:

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>

<h1 class="tlt" data-in-effect="rollIn">This should have a rollIn effect</h1>
```

It should be a very simple css animation. If anyone of you would be interested, you can view a live-demo here: http://codepen.io/jschr/pen/GaJCi.

Here is a small tutorial to use Textillate: https://github.com/jschr/textillate.

As you can see on the link above, the usage should be very basic and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first two scripts depend on jQuery, but you don't try to load jQuery until after them.

You need to load dependancies of a script before you load the script that depends on them.

Change the order of your `<script>` elements.

Comment: I see a made a mistake when writing the code, I do load jQuery first, I'll edit my original question to update the code.